# Why are all the Dawnguard NPCs holding their arms out, and can it be fixed?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues

Today I go to Dawnguard and I saw NPCs walking like this. They kind of look like a hangman stick-figure.

Almost ALL NPCs of Dawnguard are walking around with their arms like this

1. When I press E to talk
2. When they are standing

This does NOT happen to original Skyrim & HF characters. I didn't go to DB land, yet.

[image: Character looking like a hangman with his arms outstretched]

This happens to Serana too, which makes me irritated. How can I fix this?

I'm running Skyrim on PC

- Skyrim Version 1.9.32.0.8 +DG+HF+DB (latest)
- Mods (only 2):

  - UFO,
  - AP

Running from: Latest SKSE (0.1.6.16)

Comment: I Googled "hangman pause style" and was happy to have come upon this question.

Comment: I am not sure what the OP is asking... what does this even mean: "raise their hands like this"? The NPC looks like he has his hands to the sides...

Comment: @Vaishali - it's in the sense that they aren't by the NPC's side, or used in gesturing when talking. They're holding their arms out, not up.

Comment: Do you still experience the issue if you uninstall the mods you have?

Comment: Don't forget to install the unofficial patches too. They fix a lot of bugs.

Comment: Did this happen after you installed the mods? If so, that's probably the answer. Check for compatibility patches for DG.

Answer (score -1):

This also appears on my xbox, this of could be just a glitch though.
But if not, it's probably just a reusult of the AI engeneers designing the dawngaurd to have their arms out, as a catious action. As if they're holding their arms like that in case of a vampire attack. 
As for the case of it being fixed. If you haven't already uninstalled the DLC, and then installed them again (which shouldn't affect your progress) then you should, if it still persists on happening then we can presume it's supposed to be the case, as it shouldn't be too non-profitting in your case or affect the main game in any way.